# Get the stack trace of all the threads running in a process

Tags: linux, stack-trace

I wanted to know how can I get the stack traced of all threads running in a process  through a thread created by same process.

One way can be, calling signal from a thread to all the other threads and calling backtrace() in the signal handler. But this interrupts the threads. Instead of that, is there any way to get the stack trace of the threads?

Answer (score -1):

JetBrains dotTrace offering allows you to see the different threads running. You can drill into the different methods, a disassembler will show you the code for the methods and how long they take to run. It also shows hot spots where there is a potential for optimization.

https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Comment: dotTrace is .NET-specific - given the reference to `backtrace()` in the question, this appears to be aimed at native applications (likely written in C/C++).